# Water collects around cooked idlis in my steamer

Tags: indian-cuisine, steaming

I am running into a problem where water collects around my cooked idlis. I have used the steamer for about 7 years with no issues. All of a sudden, I am seeing that the top most idly tier is fine while water collects around cooked idlis in the lower tiers. The problem gets worse increases as we move down in tiers making the bottom most idly plate impossible to use. Has anybody run into a similar issue and was able to get around it?

I have tried reducing the flame and cooking longer. I have also changed the steam vent whistle. I have even tried switching the steamer! No luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using less water next time and boil the water before putting in the plates. Usually too much water is what causes the lower plates to have water.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use whistle for your steamer. For a idli steamer, there wont be any whistle. You can try a Idli steamer without steam vent whistle.